# Filter many to many relationship in Canvas app using Power fx

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, powerapps-collection

I have two tables 'Vehicle' and 'Vehicle Features' which has N:N relationship. I have a combobox to select multiple 'Vehicle Features'[Combo box to select multiple Vehicle Features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IOyQ.png).
I want to filter the list of 'Vehicles' and display it in gallery('availableVechilesGallery') when the user click the Search button which have the selected Vehicle Features from the combobox('comFeatures').

[Error is Specified Column is Not Accessible in this Context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEYtl.png)

```
//didn't work
    ForAll(Vehicles, Collect(filteredFeatVehicles,ThisRecord.'Vehicle Features' in comFeatures.SelectedItems));


    //didn't work
    ClearCollect(filteredVech, Filter(Vehicles, 'Vehicle Features'.Name in comFeatures.SelectedItems.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearCollect(
        colFilteredVehicles,        
        Filter(
            Vehicles As Vec,
            !(false in ForAll(
                comFeatures.SelectedItems, Name in Vec.'Vehicle Features'.Name
            ))
        )
    );
```

There is an option in settings under Experimental tab "Record scope one-to-many and many-to-many relationships" which needs to be toggled on for above formula to work. Looping through the N:N data requires this settings turned on.

[image: Record scope one-to-many and many-to-many relationships image]